# Touchpad delay, change drivers?

Tags: touchpad

This question has probably been asked many times before, but I can't find a working solution.

I made a fresh installation with Ubuntu 22.04. The mouse cursor has a slight delay, and doesn't stop directly when finger stops, making it very hard to navigate and click on buttons.

Can I somehow replace current touchpad drivers? How? Replace with what?